# How to detect changes in ECR image when using sam deploy and CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a CF template and ECR image referenced in this template

```
Image: !Sub <registry_id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<repo_name>:${AWS::StackName}
```

If I update an image and then run

```
sam deploy --template-file devops/templates/${CFFILENAME}.yml \
      --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --stack-name "${STACK_NAME}" \
      --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

It won't detect any changes and I have to run

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster Env-${STACK_NAME}-ClusterALB --service Env-Backend --force-new-deployment
```

To update ECS task later in the pipeline, but it is causing stack drift.
I would like to avoid it and do it all in one step in my CI pipeline and only using CF.
Is there any pretty way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After giving it a bit more thought - this is what I came up with.
I introduced new parameter in my cloudformation file such as:

```
Parameters:
  ImageTag:
    Description: "Image SHA"
    Type: String
```

Then I referenced it in task definition

```
 ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: admin
          Essential: true
          Image: !Sub <repo_id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<repo_name>:${AWS::StackName}-${ImageTag}
```

And passed in the parameter to SAM using `--parameter-overrides` as follows:

```
      sam deploy --template-file devops/templates/${CFFILENAME}.yml \
      --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --stack-name "${STACK_NAME}" \
      --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
      --parameter-overrides ImageTag=${IMAGE_TAG}
```

And the image tag is generated during the pipeline in GitLab CI using commit SHA as follows:

```
  - IMAGE_TAG="$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | head -c 8)"
```